# ProFTPD accounts

Tags: ftp, passwd

I have inherited a server where ProFTPD is installed. I can login to it with account `joe_test` and its password - **but** the problem is there is no such user as `joe_test` in `/etc/passwd`. If I do `ls -la` of `/var/ftp` then `/var/ftp/joe_test` is: `drwxr-xr-x  11 2022          ftpgroup    512 Jul 31 13:13 joe_test` as you can see `2022` is user id. My question is - where ProFTPD is storing it's passwd? (as I guess it have its own passwd file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct from the [`proftpd` docs](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/VirtualUsers.html):

> Question: If virtual users are not defined in the system /etc/passwd file, then where are they defined?
>
> Answer: There are several other locations where user information can be stored, e.g. AuthUserFiles, LDAP directories, SQL databases, and RADIUS servers. Note that virtual users are not defined in the proftpd.conf file directly.

So the answer is "It depends". You'll need to look at your `/etc/proftpd.conf` file to determine which method(s) are in use.

Comment: thanks. it seems that this configuration uses MySQL. what a stupid way to do it - any specific reason to do SQL quota rather than set size limit in `ftpd` configuration, eh?